# For loop / LinkedList runtime is to slow

Tags: java, linked-list, runtime

I need some help trying to make my algorithm more efficient. I'm trying to make my algorithm run faster (run time) than it already does. I'm testing it with lots of data.. My problem is that right now it is too slow.. maybe because of for loops..

Have 2x linked lists which is going to make the same size. Here is some code.

```
//vertices in graph
private int v;

// Contains edges represented as adjacency lists
private static LinkedList<Integer>[] edges;
private static LinkedList<Integer>[] Relations;
```

When creating them, i do this in my construcktor.

```
edges = (LinkedList<Integer>[]) new LinkedList[v];
Relations = (LinkedList<Integer>[]) new LinkedList[v];

for (int i = 0; i < vertices; i++) {
    edges[i] = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    Relations[i] = new LinkedList<Integer>();
}
```

If vertices is, lets say 10.. there is no problem.. but what if its 20000+ , then it going to run it 20000+...
Is there a way to make this more efficient?

Have read about that iterate is faster than for loop.. is it?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146797/Fast-and-Less-Fast-Loops-in-C

Comment: also - do you need the dynamic nature of a linked list or can you use a fixed size array?

Comment: Yes, i pretty much need to do this with linkedlists..

Comment: How many integers do you need to put into it at once? If you use arrays and have a fixed size to begin with you can just access by index and then expand the size later on and using the array copy functions.

Comment: Well.. i have a fixed size.. but my teacher said that linkedlists is the way to use here when creating a graph.. maybe it's not this, that is causing the slow run time for my algorithm ..

Comment: Unless you're generating a graph with random data or loading it from something like a file, I would hold off on allocating so many objects at once. Allocate objects as you need them to cut down on memory costs and initial load times. It may require rethinking the algorithm a bit/class a bit.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the for loop that's a problem its the sheer number of objects you are creating

Comment: @Raaydk it depends on your requirements